How does this delay circuit work?
Just wondering if there is an explanation to how this "delay circuit" works.

(Above screenshot from YouTube video "Fun with Transistors" at timestamp 716s (11m 56s) by HackMeMod)
I tried to make it at Falstad. The "delay part" is circled.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if you want an explanation, then why ask is there an explanation?, why not ask what is the explanation?

The guy knows what he is talking about, but the schematic at 17:20 has too be the worst I've seen in recent memory.  He drew the schematic to mimic the placement of the components on the board.  This is a huge mistake, especially when instructing persons.  A schematic is a specific tool for a specific job - it shows the relationships of the signals, not the parts.

The board shows a flipflop, but the schematic shows an oscillator.  Which are you asking about?

My question is how does the oscillation happens? It is at 12:19 timestamp

The circuit you show is called a relaxation oscillator. It's also called an astable multivibrator, which is essentially a flip-flop with phase-shifted feedback to make it oscillate. The capacitor is part of the feedback path.
Here's a simplified concept using a single inverter (simulate it here):

This shows the basic operation using feedback. The buffer has a symbol in the middle indicating an important feature: hysteresis. Hysteresis is positive feedback inside the buffer that separates high and low thresholds from each other. This separation is essential for the oscillator to work at all, otherwise it will get stuck in the middle.
I did try your simulation, it does in fact work. It takes a while to reach its initial bias point, you have to be patient (or speed up the sim.)
At any rate I've redrawn your circuit to make it a bit easier to understand, and I've added a power switch because it matters (simulate it here):

Big picture: like the simpler version above, the capacitor is charging or discharging to each polarity depending on the flip-flop state. The circuit cleverly arranges the capacitor and feedback paths to address both start-up and hysteresis.
Here's what it does:

After power-on both Q1 and Q2 are on.
Cap charges up to an initial bias state
Because Q2 has two 1k in series to its base, it turns off first
Cap now starts charging up more rapidly through Q1 base
The cap reaches its charge state, Q1 turns off, Q2 turns on
Cap discharges until its end state, Q2 turns off, Q1 turns on
etc.


Thanks for the detailed explanantion. Possibly noob question.
Because Q2 has two 1k in series to its base, it turns off first .
Do you mean it turns ON first? atleast that is what the simulation shows. Can you explain, why?

I think you’re confusing with the LED is doing with with the transistor is doing. When the transistor is on the LED is off and vice versa. As I explained, in the simulation, both transistors are on at power on. It takes a while for the circuit to reach its initial biased point but once it does, Q2 will turn off first. This is because it has more base resistance to the capacitor than Q1.
